# Difference between oracle function,procedures and PostgreSQL functions,Stored Procedures?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, function, stored-procedures

Can Any one please let me know Difference between oracle function,procedures and PostgreSQL functions,Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 2):

That question is too broad, but I'll try to enumerate some of the major differences:

- They are written in different languages. Oracle has PL/SQL and Java, while with PostgreSQL you can use almost any language you want.

  PostgreSQL's PL/pgSQL is a clone of PL/SQL, but there are significant differences.
- The syntax of the `CREATE FUNCTION` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements is quite different:

  - PostgreSQL has the code as a string literal, Oracle doesn't.
  - The syntax for declaring function results differs quite a bit.
  - Both systems have set returning functions (Orable calls them “pipelined”), but the syntax is different.
- Oracle has a huge body of libraries in its data dictionary that makes upgrades a pain, but is very useful for writing functions. PostgreSQL has little of that, you typically write Perl or Python functions to interact with the system.
- Support for procedures has only recently been added to PostgreSQL (v11), so they are not feature-complete yet.
- You cannot have transaction management in PostgreSQL functions, and you cannot have what Oracle calls an “autonomous transaction”

  You can work around some of these restrictions to some extent, but it is not the same.
- Oracle functions are executed in the user context of the owner by default, while in PostgreSQL the default is to run them in the user context of the invoker.